# How to trim the particular characters from the string in IOS?

Tags: objective-c

I have a value from the key which is as : 2016-01-13 04:02:20. But only i want to display only 2016-01-13 in my UILabel text. How to achieve this? Is there any way to trim the time from the key?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could do like this,

```
 NSString *myString = @"2016-01-13 04:02:20";
 NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, [myString rangeOfString:@" "].location)];
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
NSString *YourString = @"2016-01-13 04:02:20";
YourString=[YourString substringToIndex:10];
```

OR

```
NSString *YourString = @"2016-01-13 04:02:20";
[YourString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, [YourString rangeOfString:@" "].location)];
```

OR

```
NSArray *arrSepValue;
NSString *YourString = @"2016-01-13 04:02:20";
arrSepValue = [YourString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSString *DateStr=[arrSepValue objectAtIndex:0];
```